# How could this piece of drop() and sum() code avoid a PerformanceWarning?

Tags: pandas, numpy

`df['sum'] = df.drop('date', axis='columns').sum(axis='columns')`

It's basically just a time series with a lot of rows and a lot of columns of just floats and I just want to append a new column at the end of it that sums each whole row into each cell of the `sum` column.

Is it unavoidable that I get this warning and I should just suppress it or is there a method I miss?

PS the warning: `` PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()` ``

Comment: oof I just realized what might be doing it. the final assignment itself in isolation might be inefficient. I might answer it myself or delete it if nobody answers if I clear it up.